# How do I set a new default size for Hierarchical rectangles or other shapes in OmniGraffle?

Tags: diagrams, omnigraffle

How do I set the default size for rectangles in a Hierarchical diagram? Most of the labels I'm using are two long to fit in the current default size. I can select all the rectangles and then adjust the size, but I'd like to do this for all new diagrams. It would also be useful to just know how to set the default size of any shape.